# chef centos 7 openvpn service

Tags: chef-infra, centos7

My custom cookbook installs openvpn in the following way:

```
package 'openvpn'

... do some configuration ....

service 'openvpn' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

Code above works fine in centos 6 and fails in centos 7 (systemd)

Error: /bin/systemctl enable openvpn - No such file or directory

It seams that on systemd the name of the service is different: openvpn@server How can I detect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check platform_version (assuming you are already checking platform for CentOS in your cookbook) then switch the service_name on the fly. For example, to start OpenVPN server

```
service 'openvpn_service' do
  if node['platform_version'].to_f >= 7.0
    service_name 'openvpn@server.service'
  else
    service_name 'openvpn'
  end
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Instead of checking platform_version I'm doing this now: File.exists?('/usr/lib/systemd/system')